# Is there a built-in function to make part of a thread not run concurrently?

Tags: c++, pthreads

So my question is, is there a build-in function to make part of a thread not run concurrently in c++ with pthreads, or do I have to make something myself with a token or something like that.

Comment: Please be more concrete.  "concurrently" is a relative term -- two threads run concurrently to each other.

Comment: critical section, semaphore, mutex, lock, ... a few terms to look up.

Comment: You mean as in "make all other threads wait while I do this"? No, you'll need to manage that yourself.

Comment: The issue that I have is with the function ssh_connect() from the library libssh. When I run it I get a strange error when multiple threads are executing the function ssh_connect(). So what I mean is, is it possible to make sure the execution of the function ssh_connect is finished before another thread start with it.

Comment: Ok, then I know what to do. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Use a separate SSH instance for each thread?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Mutual Exclusion, or mutex. Standard C++, no pthreads needed. The header is called just `<mutex>`, and the type is just `std::mutex`.

One trick is how you lock it: `std::lock_guard<mutex> lock(yourSshMutex)` - this lock object keeps the mutex locked while it exists, `lock_guard::~lock_guard` unlocks it. This prevents you from forgetting to unlock a mutex when done.